# Does UAA require the login-server to have scope uaa.user?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I've got a deployment where I'm running the UAA sample apps, along with the Java login-server.  I've configured my UAA and login-server with a custom uaa.yml and login.yml, respectively.  I've populated the uaa.yml based upon the details for the "login" client by looking at the contents of /uaa/uaa/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/oauth-clients.xml, as shown below:

```
    <entry key="login">
    <map>
        <entry key="id" value="login" />
        <entry key="secret" value="loginsecret" />
        <entry key="scope" value="openid,uaa.user" />
        <entry key="authorized-grant-types" value="client_credentials,authorization_code" />
        <entry key="authorities" value="oauth.login" />
        <entry key="autoapprove" value="true" />
    </map>
</entry>
```

Configured this accordingly in my uaa.yml.  This seemed to work fine, and I can log in and surf the sample app.

However, when I subsequently visited the /approvals page in the sample app, I got a javascript error in approvals.jsp which was apparently caused by the absence of any corresponding entry for scope.uaa.user in the messages.properties file.

```
[2013-03-20 18:05:52.787] login/login-server - ???? [http-8080-1] .... DEBUG --- DispatcherServlet: Could not complete request
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'scope.uaa.user' for locale 'en_US'.
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:491)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)  
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    ...
```

So, the question is -- is scope "uaa.user" really required by the login-server? And, if so, what should the entry in the messages.properties file say?  I couldn't find any place that provided the agreed upon text description for uaa.user scope.

As a workaround, I've simply made up my own text for that scope in messages.properties, and the approvals page now renders OK.

Thanks,
John

Comment: That's logged at DEBUG so pretty much ignorable.  It doesn't stop the app from working functionally, right, just renders as a default message on the approvals screen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "uaa.user" is required by the login server. You can have any text string in the messages.properties file, which you will use in your application accordingly.
Let me know if that helps.

Thanks,

- Hitesh

Comment: Thanks. Since the scope is required, its omission from the messages.properties file in the login-server is clearly a bug (albeit a small one) because that prevents the approvals page from rendering properly.  I can issue a pull request for that change.  In general, there is a requirement to keep the messages.properties file in synch with the scopes that are used.

Answer (score 0):

The login server can't predict what scopes are going to be available, as some may be custom to the application. The bug has been fixed here
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/login-server/commit/c39aa19db33c12a0d9740e2c0a53698b87889ebc
If no message is available to represent the scope, simply print out the name of the scope.

Comment: Don't post links in answers. Write down the details instead.